# Geocode plentiful internationals adresses with Postgres or QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, geocoding, address

I've got a database with a list of events (about 30 000 events) all around the world. 
I would like to geocode those. For this, I have differents column (city/state/country).
I tried to geocode with QGIS plugin MmQGis, but I've got to much requests... 
Then I wanted to try with tiger geocode, but it seems work just for US adresses.

Do you have any solution to geocode those internationals events ?

Comment: Do you have a budget to pay a geocoding service? Alternatively, what are your technical skills?

Comment: 30,000 is not that much, do you use r? you may get the city/state/country information from gadm.ogr, are your names in the same language?

Comment: Have you tried to change the `Web Service` to OpenStreetMaps in the MMQGIS geocode?

Comment: Underdark : no I don't have a budget to geocode. I know a bit of python, SQL or JS. 
Elio Diaz : I never used R. Yes, the names are in the same language.
Marco : yes I tried, but it' limited to 2500 requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to geocode plenty international addresses. I used Geopy and the Nominatum() function that call the OSM API and not the Google one (limited to 2500 per day). On 60,000 addresses it found 52,000 addresses. That is a good success rate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't find a solution directly in QGis or PostGres to geocode my adresses.
But, I did a script with Geopy librairy and it works. To write it, I was inspired by a script of Ramiro Aznar (https://github.com/ramiroaznar/geocode-with-python-using-geopy/blob/master/geocode-with-geopy.py) to write my code.
Apparently, geopy can work directly in PostGres... To be continued !